# User Defined Functions Security Risk

Tags: cassandra

I read that if I set my enable_user_defined_functions true in the cassandra.yaml then the User defined functions (UDFs) present a security risk, since they are executed on the server side. In Cassandra 3.0 and later, UDFs are executed in a sandbox to contain the execution of malicious code. They are disabled by default.
My question is are they executed in the sandbox after I set enable_user_defined_functions true?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly set `enable_user_defined_functions_threads` to false (which you really shouldn't do) the UDFs will be run asynchronously to a pool locked down with limited security manager and special class loader.

You should still only allow trusted sources for your UDF code though incase there are security bugs.

Comment: If I explicitly set `enable_user_defined_functions` to true will my UDFs execute in sandbox?

Comment: And also if I set the above true will my cassandra node be more vulnerable to attacks externally?

Comment: Yes it will always execute in the sandbox. No it does not make it any more open to attacks externally. What it does is make it probably more dangerous if somehow an attacker gains ability to run arbitrary CQL commands with admin/schema update rights (although if they can do this you are in trouble regardless). It might be a concern if your doing some kinda multi tenancy and allow different customers access but dont want them effecting each other - although this is something that Cassandra doesn't support either.